# Why I can't change the visibility of my ImageView with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The ImageView changes visibility only once. I can't understand what could be the problem.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        println("Let's do it")
        val btn: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        while (true) {
            Handler().postDelayed({
                btn.isVisible = true
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    btn.isVisible = false
                }, 1000)
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're posting _a lot_ of delayed runnables, since the othermost `postDelayed` calls will happen repeatedly with no delay inbetween.

Comment: code : create millions of handlers and runnables, as fast as possible ... ui : screams "give me a break!"

Comment: @Michael How can I make it right? I just trying to change the visibility of view every second.

Comment: @DanGal remove the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minimal example :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var target : ImageView
    private val handler : Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val runnable : Runnable  = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            target.isVisible = !target.isVisible
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1_000)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        target  = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1_000)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I make the delay smaller than a millisecond?

Comment: No and that would be pointless seeing as the "frame" is drawn every 16 milliseconds (60fps).  Runnables and Handlers are not ideal for rapid UI updates.  Usually you's use the `Animator` framework or custom views and have full control of the canvas. Not really sure of your use case to ask such a question.

Answer (score 0):

let's simplify this code

```
        while (true) { // you will keep running this 
            Handler().postDelayed({
                ... // this code will won't be exec until 1000ms 
            }, 1000)
        }
```

So you can see , 1000ms you will add so many messages in message queue .
OK, let's see 1000-2000ms this period:
At this period , handler will do two thing :

1. keep posting delay message in handler
2. exec the previous 1000ms message

Step 2 will also do two things :

1. set visible = true
2. post an message the make visible = false

So let's see 2000-3000ms :
this time will do 3 things :

1. keep posting delay message in handler
2. exec the previous 1000ms message
3. exec the step2's message

step3 will do one thing ; make view invisible.

So :
0-1000ms : the view do nothing .
1000-2000ms : view will be set visible
2000- : **view will be set visible and invisible very quickly so that you can't tell the difference .**

Answer (score 0):

You are doing one thing wrong

```
btn.isVisible = true
 btn.isVisible = false
```

It should be

```
btn.visibility = GONE
btn.visibility = VISIBLE
```

Comment: not if using `View.kt` extensions.  This is not the "one" thing that's wrong.